# Is it possible to resurrect Jarl Maven Black-Briar?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I killed Jarl [Maven Black-Briar](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Maven_Black-Briar) using a console command, however a later mission requires her to be alive for part of the mission.

Is it possible to resurrect her?

Answer (score 1):

```
recycleactor 00019DD1
```

Another method of doing it, while in Riften:

```
prid 00019DD1
moveto player
ressurect 1
```

If the NPC is not shown after the `moveto` command, you might need to use `enable` after that.

Sources:

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Maven_Black-Briar

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs

You can use this command on PC to resurrect her. Just press "^" (QWERTZ Keyboard) or "~" (QWERTY Keyboard) to open the console.

Comment: I didn't work but i found out how to resurrect her. So it's cool.

Comment: You might wanna tell why it did not work and what you did to solve it. This command worked for me, just checked it in Skyrim. If the reference ID is different, which is unlikely, you can always click on her body to get the ID displayed.